# express-handlebars throwing type error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, express, types, handlebars.js, ts-node

```js
import express from 'express';
import { engine } from 'express-handlebars';
const app = express();
app.engine("hbs", engine()) // This line trows an error:
```

[image: Argument of type 'Engine' is not assignable to parameter of type '(path: string, options: object, callback: (e: any, rendered?: string) => void) => void'.]

I have the following dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "express-handlebars": "^6.0.1",
  "morgan": "^1.10.0",
  "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
  "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
  "typescript": "^4.4.4",
  "ts-node": "^10.4.0"
}
```

I've tried looking around and couldn't find anything about it using TypeScript.

Hope someone can help; and thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code has no type errors in the typescript playground: https://tsplay.dev/mZbGam

Comment: It works in module JS but it doesn't run when using ts-node or nodemon and throws that same error. I'll use JS for now but I'll leave the question open since I couldn't find any resources on this with TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in express documentation:

> Some template engines do not follow this convention, the
> [Consolidate.js](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js) library was created to map all of node's popular
> template engines to follow this convention, thus allowing them to work
> seamlessly within Express.

That said here is an example for [Consolidate](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js), Express, and TypeScript:

```
import express from "express";
import cons from "consolidate";

const app = express();
app.engine("html", cons.handlebars);
app.set("view engine", "html");
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!